# Installation of GMP PHP library in XAMPP doesn't work

Tags: php, xampp, gmp

I try to use the [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) library for big integers in PHP.
I use XAMPP, PHP 5.5.11, and Ubuntu 14.04.

According to several sources it should be as easy as that:

run `sudo apt-get install php5-gmp`
put `extension=php_gmp.so` or `extension=gmp.so` in php.ini
restart XAMPP

Then it should work, and in phpinfo() I should see the GMP version.
But nothing works. I also tried the rather unhelpful hints in the [installation guide](http://php.net/manual/en/gmp.installation.php).

What's wrong?

Comment: "What's wrong?" We don't know. You tell us...

Comment: I mean: What kind of tests could I run, to find out, why the steps that worked for others don't work for me?

Comment: 1.) Check if the library has been installed by apt-get. 2.) Check if you're editing the right php.ini 3.) Check PHP startup errors.

Comment: 3.)I indeed have a PHP startup error: `[27-Oct-2014 00:33:42 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/gmp.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/gmp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: So the software expected `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/gmp.so`, and I had `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/gmp.so`. I copied it there, and now it works. Thanks for the hint with the startup errors. I don't get, why you downvote my question. Sometimes further investigation needs a little hint where to look, like the one I just got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint that has answered this question for me was given by hakre in a comment:

If the installation has worked, and the right php.ini was edited, but after restart of XAMPP there is still the `Fatal error:  Call to undefined function gmp_foo() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bar/barf.php on line 123`, it may be a good idea to look for startup errors in the PHP error log. For me it was in `/opt/lampp/logs/php_error_log`.

There it showed the same error after every restart of XAMPP. As shown in the comments, the problem was that gmp.so was not in the expected folder. After I copied it there, everything worked, and in the phpinfo() is now a gmp section with the entries:
`gmp support    enabled`
`GMP version    5.1.3`

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment `extension=php_gmp.dll` line. To uncomment simply remove `;`